# Checking whether a complex function has an antiderivative in given areas

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Let's consider a complex function
$$f(z) = \frac{4z^3}{z^4 + 16}, \quad z \in \mathbb{C}. \tag{1}$$

Moreover let's consider two areas

1. $A = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| < 2 \},$
2. $B = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| > 2 \}.$

I am to check whether $(1)$ has an antiderivative in area $A$ and $B$.

I know that $(1)$ can be rewritten as
$$f(z) = \frac{4z^3}{(z - z_1)(z - z_2)(z-z_3)(z-z_4)},$$
where
$$z_1 = \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{2}i, \quad z_2 = -\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{2}i, \quad z_3 = \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{2}i, \quad z_4 = \sqrt{2} - \sqrt{2}i.$$

That means that $f(z)$ is holomorphic both in $A$ and $B$. To my mind that implies that $f(z)$ has an antiderivative in both areas. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

No, you are not.

The restriction of $f$ to $A$ has an antiderivative. For instance, you can take$$F(z)=\int_{\gamma_z}f(u)\,\mathrm du,$$with $\gamma_z\colon[0,1]\longrightarrow A$ defined by $\gamma_z(t)=tz$.

However, it follows from the residue theorem that $\int_{\lvert z\rvert=4}f(z)\,\mathrm dz=8\pi i$ (the residue of $f$ at each one of its four poles is $1$) and therefore the restriction of $f$ to $B$ cannot have an antiderivative.

Comment: How to check in general whether a restriction of a function has an antiderivative? It's hard to show that every contour integral for contours in an area is equal to zero.

Comment: If the region is [star convex](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StarConvex.html), then $f$ always has an antiderivative. This applies to your region $A$.

Comment: Always? Even if there are some points in which the denominator is zeroing?

Comment: If the denominator has a zero, then that point is **not** part of the domain. And if you remove a point (or a finite set of points) from a star convex open set, then it will not be star convex anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Having an antiderivative (primitive) in a region,  is equivalent to the integral around any closed curve being zero.

For $\vert z\vert\lt2$:  the function is analytic,  with power series $f(z)=\frac14\sum_{n\ge0} (-\frac1{16})^n( z)^{4n+3}$. Hence has an antiderivative, since the integral around any closed path is zero (by Cauchy's theorem).

For $\vert z\vert\gt2$:  the residue at each pole $z_0$ is $\frac {4z_0^3}{4z_0^3}=1$.  Hence the integral around a closed curve is not zero (by the Residue theorem).   Hence no antiderivative.